# Constructing a JSON string properly in Java

Tags: java, json

Is there a better way to do this? This looks really ugly.
My input object is like:

```
{
    "Field":"name",
    "Record":{
        "Recordvalue1": "value1",
        "Recordvalue2": "value2",
        "Recordvalue2": "value2"
    }
}
```

I want to strip the inner object and let it be its own `JSONObject` using the simple library.

```
  public static JSONObject Strippingquitely(JSONObject inputobj) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject finalobj = null;
    try {
      finalobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse((inputobj.get("Record")).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
    return finalobj;
  }
}
```

Comment: `return (JSONObject)inputobj.get("Record");`

Comment: Much better solution, thankyou, will try when I get home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to reparse anything.

A JSONObject has that get method which returns the inner object, not a string. You may need to cast accordingly, depending on the library you are using and the methods available, though.

For example  `return  (JSONObject)  inputobj.get("Record")`

But if you used a different library, `inputobj.getObject("Record")` might be available

Comment: I posted the library i'm using in the initial post

Comment: You said "simple" library. Is that supposed to mean `JSON.simple`?